# Cannot get response body from mock bin

Tags: mocking, endpoint

I am using http://mockbin.org service to create some mock bin for testing request, but response haven't response body.

I have created mock bin according to official doc https://mockbin.org/docs#request-bin for this I perform the following request

```
POST /bin/create HTTP/1.1
Host: mockbin.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 01dd1ca5-5f0f-4ba5-b4bf-11e84f9473a0

{
   "status": 200,
   "statusText": "OK",
   "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
   "headers": [
     {
       "name": "Content-Type",
       "value": "application/json"
     }
   ],
   "cookies": [],
   "content": {
     "mimeType": "application/json",
     "text": "{\n    \"foo\": \"Hello Word\"\n}"
   }
 }
```

And get the following response:

> ```
> b1db6c53-581b-495e-9db7-9bffd6befa8c
> ```

Next I try to perform the following request with this bin id

> ```
> POST /bin/b1db6c53-581b-495e-9db7-9bffd6befa8c HTTP/1.1
> ```

But I haven't a body in this result.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: The old mockbin is offline. I’d recommend trying https://mockbin.io.